# How to check multiple textareas for input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently asked a question about how to add a colored border to a textarea when checking for none-empty textareas. I now found out that my code only checks for 1 filled-in textarea and then it will validate the form.

**How can I edit the following code to make sure that it checks each textarea so that all of them need to have input.**

```
function validate() {

    var success = true;

    var inputarea = $('#input-area textarea');

    for(i = 0; i < inputarea.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputarea.val() === "")
        {
            console.log("Missing textarea input");
            $('#input-area textarea').fadeIn().html('').css("border","1px solid red");

            success = false;
        }
    }

    return success;       
}
```

Everything else works the way I want it to, I just have to make sure it checks all textareas for input, not just if 1 textarea as input.

Comment: This script assumes you have multiple textareas with the same ID `input-area`. This is illegal use of HTML. Use a class!

Comment: @SterlingArcher, no, it assumes that all `textarea` elements are descendants of an element with `id="input-area"`. But we cannot know from the question whether thet actually are.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate code fragment with corresponding jsFiddle.

In the HTML we have two text areas.

```
Area 1
<textarea rows="4"></textarea>
<br/>
Area 2
<textarea rows="4"></textarea>
<br/>
<button>Validate</button>
```

And here is the meat of the logic:

```
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    $("textarea").each(function(index, element) {
        if (valid == true) {
            valid = $(element).val().length > 0;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}

$("button").click(function() {
    alert("Valid = " + validate());
});
```

There is a function called validate() that returns true only if ALL textareas on the page have content and false otherwise.  When the button is clicked, a call to the validate function is made and the result shown in an alert box.  Hopefully the code is self explanatory but if not, examine each of the corresponding jQuery methods against its reference.  If there is still mystery, post a comment back and I will try and elaborate.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/m03rkfcL/)

Answer (score -1):

Please check with this sample code..You need to use classes name instead of Id.If you want to check multiple values you need to use class

```
<script>
function validate() {


    var success = true;

    var inputarea = $('.input-area');

    for(i = 0; i < inputarea.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputarea[i].value.trim() === "") // TRIM() is IE9+
        {
            console.log("Missing textarea input");
            $(inputarea[i]).fadeIn().html('').css("border","1px solid red");

            success = false;
        }
    }

    return success;       
}
</script>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
     <textarea class="input-area"></textarea>
      <textarea class="input-area"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: -1 for simply dumping out code. Explain why this should work

Comment: That is what Iam trying to edit @SterlingArcher.Before only You posted the comment..I have explained

Comment: Also, presumably the fadeIn is supposed to fadeIn the offending textarea, not all of them?